# how bytes are used to store information in protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

i am trying to understand the protocol buffer here is the sample , what i am not be able to understand is how bytes are being used in following messages. i dont know what this number 
`1 2 3` is used for.

```
message Point {
  required int32 x = 1;
  required int32 y = 2;
  optional string label = 3;
}

message Line {
  required Point start = 1;
  required Point end = 2;
  optional string label = 3;
}

message Polyline {
  repeated Point point = 1;
  optional string label = 2;
}
```

i read following paragraph in google protobuf but not able to understand what is being said here , can anyone help me in understanding how bytes are being used to store info.

The " = 1", " = 2" markers on each element identify the unique "tag" that field uses in the binary encoding. Tag numbers 1-15 require one less byte to encode than higher numbers, so as an optimization you can decide to use those tags for the commonly used or repeated elements, leaving tags 16 and higher for less-commonly used optional element.

Answer (score 4):

The general form of a protobuf message is that it is a sequence of pairs of the form:

- field header
- payload

For your question, we can largely forget about the payload - that isn't the bit that relates to the 1/2/3 and the <=16 restriction - all of that is in the field header. The field header is a "varint" encoded integer; "varint" uses the most-significant-bit as an optional continuation bit, so small values (<=127, assuming unsigned and not zig-zag) require one byte to encode - larger values require multiple bytes. Or in other words, you get 7 useful bits to play with before you need to set the continuation bit, requiring at least 2 bytes.

However! The field header itself is composed of two things:

- the wire-type
- the field-number / "tag"

The wire-type is the first 3 bits, and indicates the fundamental format of the payload - "length-delimited", "64-bit", "32-bit", "varint", "start-group", "end-group". That means that of the 7 useful bits we had, only 4 are left; 4 bits is enough to encode numbers <= 16. **This** is why field-numbers <= 16 are suggested (as an optimisation) for your most common elements.

In your question, the 1 / 2 / 3 is the field-number; at the time of encoding this is left-shifted by 3 and composed with the payload's wire-type; then this composed value is varint-encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf stores the messages like a map from an id (the =1, =2 which they call tags) to the actual value. This is to be able to more easily extend it than if it would transfer data more like a struct with fixed offsets. So a message `Point` for instance would look something like this on a high level:

```
1 -> 100,
2 -> 500
```

Which then is interpreted as `x=100`, `y=500` and `label=not set`. On a lower level, protobuf serializes this tag-value mapping in a highly compact format, which among other things, stores integers with variable-length encoding. The paragraph you quoted just highlights exactly this in the case of tags, which can be stored more compactly if they are < 16, but the same for instance holds for integer values in your protobuf definition.